# Creating a one-way binding for buttons

Tags: swift, button, binding, swiftui

I've been trying to test some codes here but I can't get it to work.

So for the principle of how I want this to work:

In this single View, After pressing the first hello button, it should run a function to determine what the next 4 buttons show. I am not sure how to create this one-way binding to allow running of the function and make 4 buttons appear after pressing.

I keep getting this error:

> Result of 'Button' initializer is unused

Things I've tried:

1. adding the 4 buttons to be appeared in the closure of the 1st Hello button, nothing appears after clicking but it compiles!

Can someone please help?

```
var toggle1 = false
var buttonArray = [12,25,33,4]
var numberArray = [Int]()

func convertingIntoImage() {
    for numbers in buttonArray {
        let numberInString = String(numbers)
        numberArray = numberInString.compactMap {str in Int(numberInString)}
    }
}

struct tryingOut : View {
    var body : some View {
        
        Button(action: { convertingIntoImage() } ) {
            Text("hello")
        }

        Button(action: { print("Hello") } ) {
            ForEach (numberArray, id: \.self) {
                Image(systemName: "\($0)" + ".circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle1 = false
    @State var buttonArray = [12, 25, 33, 4]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !toggle1 {
                Button(action: { self.toggle1.toggle() }) {
                    Text("hello")
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: { print("Hello") }) {
                    ForEach(buttonArray, id: \.self) {
                        Image(systemName: "\($0)" + ".circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need a separate function to convert `buttonArray`. And you can use a `toggle` to switch between showing the `hello` button and your four images.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I just tried your code but the live preview doesn't seem to have an effect on changing from 1 button to 4 buttons after toggling. I also tried with my original code, with my vars and functions put in an ObservableOject class. That doesn't update the view either after toggling to change from 1 button to 4. Do you know what may have gone wrong? Thanks! oh I tried both live and debug preview too. thanks!

Comment: @LCHUNG Oh, right. I should've used a `VStack` instead of a `Group`. I updated my code - now it works in previews as well.

Comment: ahh! Thank you! Do you happen to know why Group doesn't do the job? I'd have never thought Group was the culprit.

Comment: @LCHUNG `Group` itself isn't the problem. When you put `Group` inside `VStack` it will work in previews as well. Only `Group` at the top level (in the `body`) will break previews. Looks like the top level `View` is not dynamically refreshed in previews.